# NodeJS cannot read property 'on' of undefined

Tags: node.js

I am encountering a wear error message on NodeJS and I have been looking around with no success. I have looked at similar questions, but nothing help to fix the error. I am trying to create a Duplex Stream but whenever I run it, I am receiving the error message from Node as it 'cannot read property 'on' of undefined. However every thing seems right in the code below. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
//duplex stream used for read and writing

var stream = require('stream');
var util = require('util');

util.inherits(ReadWrite, stream.Duplex);

function ReadWrite(opt){

stream.Duplex.call(this, opt);
this.array = [];
};

//register two functions read and write 
ReadWrite.prototype._read = function(size){

//stores the first item 
var data = this.array.shift(); 

if(data == 'stop'){

    this.push(null);
}
else{

    if(data){

        this.push(data);
    }
    else{

        setTimeout(_read.bind(this), 500, size);
    }
}
};


 ReadWrite.prototype._write = function(data, encode, callback){

  this.array.push(data);
  callback;
 };

//testing

var buf = ReadWrite();

 buf.on('data', function(data){

  console.log('Read: ' + data.toString());
 });

 buf.on('end', function(){

    console.log('Message complete!');
 });

 buf.write('Bonjour');
 buf.write("C'est Moi");
 buf.write('On dit quoi?');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't there a typo here?

`ReadWrite.prototype_write = function(data, encode, callback){`

You wrote **prototype_write** instead of `prototype._write`.

The following works:

```
function ReadWrite(opt){
  // this is needed if you don't use new ReadWrite()
  if(!this instanceof ReadWrite){
    return new ReadWrite(opt)
  }
  Duplex.call(this, opt);
}

util.inherits(ReadWrite, Duplex);

var test = new ReadWrite()
```

You forgot to use `new ReadWrite()` when creating an instance.

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out, I just fixed it but I still have the error message about but.on property

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I can believe I overlooked this part of my code. I guess coding pass midnight is not effective for me :) . Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You do this:

```
var buf = ReadWrite();
buf.on(...)
```

But, `ReadWrite()` does not return anything as it is just this code:

```
function ReadWrite(opt){
    stream.Duplex.call(this, opt);
    this.array = [];
};
```

Perhaps you mean to do this instead so it will create a new `ReadWrite` object and return it as this is the usual way to create new objects with `new`:

```
var buf = new ReadWrite();
```